# changing from percona to mariadb without losing data

Tags: mysql, mariadb, percona

i have a production server running with percona.
but i don't really like it anymore and i'm more used to mariadb.
can i change from percona to mariadb without losing any data or having compatibility issues afterwards?
if so, is it as simple as ~ remove percona ~ and ~ install mariadb ~ or is there anything else to be aware of?

i will of course make a backup before i do the change, but would like to know it anyway.
if i use ~ --purge remove ~ on percona will i lose my datadir as well?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would play it safe and use `mysqldump` to export current databases to backups, and then import those files to the new database server.

This is because the data format might be incompatible between MariaDB and Percona.

Comment: or the admin tables, or the version